# Unable to compile 'sass' when trying to install package with R

Tags: r, ubuntu, sass, r-markdown, rstudio

When running `install.packages("sass")` in *Rstudio*, the download succeeds but an error occurs in the compilation :

```bash
...
g++ -std=gnu++14 -Wall -O2 -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/lib/libsass/include  -fPIC -c -o src/ast.o src/ast.cpp
In file included from src/ast.cpp:3:
src/sass.hpp:72:43: error: ‘SASS_STYLE_TO_CSS’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SASS_STYLE_TO_SASS’?
   72 |   const static Sass_Output_Style TO_CSS = SASS_STYLE_TO_CSS;
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                           SASS_STYLE_TO_SASS
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpvBnS6X/R.INSTALLd6174d82af25/sass/src/libsass'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:229: src/ast.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makevars:7: libsass/lib/libsass.a] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sass’
...
```

---

I have tried to install earlier versions of [rstudio/sass](https://github.com/rstudio/sass) with `install_github`, as advised [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-install-sass-package/30052), encountering the same compilation error.

---

(I need this package as a dependency for other ones, notably *rmarkdown*)

Here is my machine's information (output of `sessionInfo()`) :

```bash
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
...
```

Comment: Install a binary version.

Comment: I cannot install binary packages as my OS is ubuntu

Comment: Your information is a bit out of date on this issue. Dirk Eddelbeuttal offers a binary package repo for several flavors of Linux. As of 2020 he was supporting 18.04 and 20.04 flavors of Ubuntu, but I think recently that I saw that he had shifted to 20.04 and 22.04. https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2020/08/26/

Comment: Indeed my information was wrong, this method worked (I answered my question), thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [these slides](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/t4_007_ubuntu_binaries.pdf) (from [this blog](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2020/06/22/#027_ubuntu_binaries)), I was able to install the package running those commands :

```bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt update && apt install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+
echo ”deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/” > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cran.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
apt update && apt install -y r-cran-sass
```

Thanks to this PPA, I can now install (any other) packages from the **cran mirror** with `apt` .

Answer (score 1):

first make sure you have the necessary development tools and libraries installed on your system with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev
```

then remove the latest version of LibSass `sudo apt-get remove libsass` then install it

```
git clone https://github.com/sass/libsass.git
cd libsass
git checkout tags/3.6.5 # Replace '3.6.5' with the latest version, if necessary
make -j4
sudo make install
```

now Install the 'sass' package in R `install.packages("sass")`

if that still dont work try directly on the github

```
if (!requireNamespace("remotes", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/sass")
```

You can also try by installing the 'sass' package using the 'devtools' package in R:

first install the `devtools` package if not already `install.packages("devtools")` then load it `library(devtools)` and we try to install sass `devtools::install_github("rstudio/sass")`

if still not maybe reach them on github

Comment: I get the same compilation error (when executing `make`).

Comment: Im kinda lost then, try installing the binary directly as suggested maybe

Comment: Binary packages are only installable on MacOS and Windows, I am running Ubuntu

Comment: I have added a new solution in my answer maybe it will work :)

Comment: I cannot install `devtools`, as `sass` is one of its dependency